# F# Parallel Actor

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, f#, actor

Assume I have an actor:

```
let server (mailbox:Actor<_>) =
    let rec loop () = actor {
        let! message = mailbox.Receive()
        match message with
        | Message(num, num1, str) -> 
            printfn "Got a number %d %d %s" num num1 str
            return! loop()
    }
    loop ()
```

How to make this actor do some computation while he waits for a message to receive?

Comment: That is probably trying to use the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I suggest you google these kind of questions rather than ask them here, although it's a good question, and I'm sure there's somebody that would love to give some answer. Googling should give you lots of answers with a wide range of solutions for different use cases, and that can be more valuable than a simple answer here.

Comment: http://www.fssnip.net/tags/mailboxprocessor

Comment: I don't think the akka and akka.net tags should have been edited away, since this code uses what appears to be an Akka actor rather than F#'s built in MailboxProcessor actor type, and since Akka has mechanisms that are relevant to the question.